# How can I spawn sprites every 10 degrees around a circle?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, 2d-games

I'm very new to coding and would appreciate some help with a small game I'm making to learn.  So I have a circle and I'm trying to create objects at every 10 degree interval around the circle.  I tried this:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

     self.spawnArrows()

}

func spawnArrows() {

     for var i = 0; i < 36; i++ {

         let arrow = self.createArrow(specificPointOnCircle(Float(self.frame.size.width), center: CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)), angle: Float(i * 10)))
         self.addChild(arrow)

     }
}

func specificPointOnCircle(radius:Float, center:CGPoint, angle:Float) -> CGPoint {

    let theta = angle * Float(M_PI) + 2.0
    let x = radius * cosf(theta)
    let y = radius * sinf(theta)
    return CGPoint(x: CGFloat(x) + center.x, y: CGFloat(y) + center.y)

}

func createArrow(position: CGPoint) -> SKSpriteNode {

    let arrow = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Arrow.png")
    arrow.zPosition = 2
    arrow.size = CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width * 0.12, height: self.frame.size.width * 0.025)
    arrow.position = position
    return arrow

}
```

But nothing at all is showing up.  Is my math wrong somewhere, or my syntax, or perhaps both?  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your maths is dizzy. Print your arrow.location in `spawnArrows()`. It doesn't seem to change at all. Angle is the angle of your SpriteNode. Sorry, but I have no time to check further atm... :(

Comment: degree to radian formula is `let theta = angle * Float(M_PI) / 180`

Comment: your radius is HUGE by the way,   so huge that it is larger than your scene size,  you need to make that smaller

Comment: Setting the radius to `Float(self.frame.size.width)/10` and changing the radian formula to `let theta = angle * Float(M_PI) / 180` solved the problem for me. You should make that an answer @Knight0fDragon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue 1:

Your formula to convert degree to radian is wrong, the formula is:

```
let theta = angle * Float(M_PI) / 180
```

Issue 2:

Your radius is the entire size of your scene, so you are plotting points from the center of your scene to the length of your scene, which goes 2x beyond the scenes width.  At the very minimum, set the radius to width / 2 to get to see it at the very edge of your width

Comment: Thank you this fixed the problem!

Comment: The radius was correct (as I have the sprites then moving onto the screen later) but the radian formula was incorrect.

Comment: well the radius problem was why you weren't seeing anything from the start

Comment: As a bonus question for you, how would I get the loop to wait 1 second between iterations so that each object spawns 1 second after the last?

Comment: That is a completely different task then what you have now.  You cannot do the loop like you have it.  Instead, you need the class to have a variable that remembers what the last angle was,  and use SKActions on nodes that will wait 1 second,  then create.  There are a lot of examples on it SO, look for `SKAction.waitForDuration`,`SKAction.sequence`, and `SKAction.runBlock`.  Those 3 should help you